# GWT - RemoteDeathError

Tags: java, gwt

I've been trying to find a work around with this issue of `RemoteDeathError`.

In the browser when I open my gwt application, after a while it shows that GWT DMP Plugin has crashed

And looking the the devmode console, I can see this error:

> 00:02:49.491 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote
>   connection lost   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:354)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$ReturnMessage.send(BrowserChannel.java:1310)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$ReturnMessage.send(BrowserChannel.java:1315)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:340)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What the possible causes of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is that the client or server stacktrace? if that's the client, was there any server message?

Comment: Its client side, no distinctive server error relating to this, actually the same application works fine with Firefox, so I think this is a Chrome gwt plugin bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemoteDeathError just means the client (browser) connection was unexpectedly closed. It may be an issue with the browser or plugin. Can you try a different browser and see if it still happens?